# Java HttpURLConnection re-use policy

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

I have an object that I will be using to send a lot of HTTP POST requests to the same destination URL. I'm not sure whether I should call `openConnection()` each time I make a request? Similarly `disconnect()` each time?